# C++ Quicksort continues to crash

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime-error, quicksort

I have implemented quicksort for some time analysis and it compiles but continues to crash after running, I can't figure out why. Also I think there is an error in one of the return statements `if(high == low)` of the helper function, I don't know if this is causing my problem? The code is below, it's receiving an array of 40 randomly generated integers.

```
int partition(int A[], int low, int high) {
   //Partition the array into two parts
   //Pre Condition: A[] must have more than 2 elements
   int mid = (low + high) / 2;
   int pivot = A[mid]; //Store the value at A[mid] in our pivot
   A[mid] = A[low]; //Make a "gap" at low
   while(low < high) {
      //The "gap" is currently at low
      while(low < high && A[high] >= pivot) {
         high--;
      }
      A[low] = A[high]; //"Gap" is now at A[high]
      while(low < high && A[low] <= pivot) {
         low++;
      }
      A[high] = A[low];
      A[low] = pivot;
   }
   return low;
}

void quickSort(int A[], int low, int high) {
   //QuickSort Helper Function
   //Pre Condition: A > 0
   //Post Condition: Partition of the array
   if(low == high) //***ERROR HERE***
      return;
   if(low + 1 == high) {
      if(A[low] > A[high]) {
         swap(A, high, low);
      }
      return;
   }
   //Assign the return value to pivotPos after running partition method
   int pivotPos = partition(A, low, high); 
   quickSort(A, low, pivotPos - 1); //Recursive call
   quickSort(A, pivotPos + 1, high); //Recursive call
   return;
}

void quickSort(int A[], int n) {
   //Quicksort sorting algorithm
   //Precondition: A < 0
   //Postcondition: Sorted array in ascending order
   quickSort(A, 0, n - 1); //call our helper function
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'crash'? What error message do you get? What did the debugger say?

Comment: I use Scite I don't believe it has a debugger? I get a Windows error, as if the program was in an infinite loop. Not a error in Scite but an actual Windows .exe error

Comment: What is the error? Why not use this code in a debugger to debug the other errors you are finding? - https://www.visualstudio.com/ - has free debuggers you can use.

Comment: After a few iterations, low becomes 3 and high becomes 2 and you recursively call partition never making any progress until you run out of stack space and segfault.

Comment: So then I should change the first condition to >=

Comment: "int mid = (lo + hi)/2;" <- do "lo + (hi - lo)/2" instead

Comment: How do you generate random numbers exactly? what is the range you generate?

Comment: @P.Hinker you were correct. Thank you.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 wouldn't that cause the worst case O(n^2) to prevail more often than not

Comment: What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 thanks for your help! Issue is resolved

Comment: you should never do mid = (low + high)/2, it can cause an overflow, mid = low + (high - low) / 2 will never cause an overflow